# Accidentally overwrote mysql database with old data.

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I accidentally overwrote mysql database with old data in SQLyog by using restore method. Can I rollback it to previous data? 
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: if you've got a more recent backup then restore that - that's all you can do, really.